# how to generate a URL from JSON object?

Tags: javascript, url

**UPDATE**
Updated the JSON model

I have 2 JSON objects look like:

```
{
   "scheme":"https",
   "server":"example.com"
}
```

and

```
{
   "scheme":"https",
   "server":"example.com",
   "path":"items",
   "item":"apple",
   "itemDetails":[
      {
         "country":"US",
         "year":"2019"
      }
   ]
}
```

I want to make them into URL such as 
https://example.com or https://example.com/items?item=apple&country=US&year=2019

How can I do?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL

Comment: 1. there's no such thing as a JSON object 2. that's not valid JSON 3. what have you tried? this can be trivially solved by adding the parts together with some `"://"` in between.

Comment: What is the problem you are facing ?

Comment: this is a object and as mentioned by @ChrisG you can concat the values and obtain url from that

Comment: Will the extra keys always be `item` and `itemDetails`? And can we assume the array will always have 1 object or can it vary?

Comment: @adiga only scheme and server are fixed, others are not

Answer (score 2):

- You could create a function which creates the URL based on the object provided.

  [Destructure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) the parameter to get `scheme`, `server`, `path`. Assign a [default value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Setting_a_function_parameters_default_value) to `path` since it is optional. Get the remaining unknown properties to a `rest` variable using [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) (Properties like `item`, `itemDetails` etc will be inside the rest object)
- You can create the base URL using the first 3 variables using a [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)
- To get the query string, you can use [`URLSearchParams`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams/URLSearchParams) constructor. It has several [overloads](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams/URLSearchParams#Examples). You can pass a query string or an object or an array of entries as parameter to the constructor. If the object is flat, you simply do, `new URLSearchParams(rest).toString()` to create the query string. But, since you have nested arrays and objects, we need to create an array of entries first (Something like: `[[key1, value1], [key2, value2],...and so on]`. Then the string will be key `key1=value1&key2=value2`. The values will also be properly encoded to replace space and special characters etc)
- You can create a recursive function to get the nested entries. Loop through the entries of the given object. If the current value is an `Array`, recursively call the method for each object in the array and push it to entries. If the value is an object, recursively call the function on the value. This function will return a 2-dimensional array of all the key-value pairs in the object.
- Then simply pass the entries to `URLSearchParams` to create the query string. If the query string is not empty, append it to the base URL with a prefix of `?`.

```js
function createURL({ scheme, server, path = '', ...rest }) {
  let url = `${scheme}://${server}/${path}`;
  let param = new URLSearchParams(getEntries(rest)).toString();
  if (param)
    url += "?" + param;
  return url
}

function getEntries(o = {}) {
  const entries = [];
  for (const [k, v] of Object.entries(o)) {
    if (Array.isArray(v))
      entries.push(...v.flatMap(getEntries))
    else if (typeof v === 'object')
      entries.push(...getEntries(v))
    else entries.push([k, v])
  }
  return entries;
}

console.log(createURL({
  scheme: "https",
  server: "example.com"
}))

console.log(createURL({
  scheme: "https",
  server: "example.com",
  path: "items",
  item: "apple",
  "itemDetails": [{
    "country": "US",
    "year": "2019"
  }]
}))
```

Comment: Nice answer ! However, I think it could be tweaked a bit, if there is no path the url become `https://www.example.com/?foo=bar` instead of `https://www.example.com?foo=bar` (notice the / after `example.com`) But I don't think this is an issue

Answer (score -2):

Maybe is not the best way, but you can try

```
var myjson = {
       scheme:https,
       server:example.com
};

    var obj = JSON.parse(myjson);
    document.getElementById("#div1").innerHTML = obj.scheme + obj.server;
```

Comment: `var obj = JSON.parse(myjson);` this won't work, since `myjson` **is not** a JSON **string**

Comment: `obj.scheme + obj.server` will provide `httpsexample.com`

Comment: var obj= JSON.stringify(myjson);
document.getElementById("#div1").innerHTML = obj.scheme + "://" + obj.server;

Comment: This won't work neither since `obj` would be a string and there is no `string.scheme` nor `string.server`

Comment: It's `var obj = JSON.parse(jsonString);` or `var text = JSON.stringify(someObj);` please learn the difference. Leaving aside the syntax issues and unfortunate naming, `myjson` is already an **Object** and therefore we don't need `JSON.parse()` here, or `JSON.stringify()`.